# Android Bluetooth communication errors

Tags: android, bluetooth, serial-port

I am trying to communicate an Inertial Measurement Unit (accelerometer, gyroscope, and magnetometer) with an Android phone via Bluetooth. Specifically, I am using an MPU9150 as my IMU. I have a working code in Python that communicates to perfection with the IMU. I proceeded to port this code to Java for the Android part. I took the Bluetooth Chat example and modified it to my needs. Now it "works".

I can send data to the IMU with no problems and I can somehow receive data correctly. I am getting correct packets but every say, 4th or 5th packet, maybe more often, maybe less, I get a completely irrational packet. For example, a correct acceleration packet would look like
    0.002 0.001 0.003
while the erratic value I get would look like 
    0.002 0.001 -16,371.002

I know that my porting works because I have tested and debugged the functions that process the incoming data. The problem, in my opinion, is in the connection part. When I inspect the data that is coming in Python and Java, Java packets show this completely irrational data since the moment they arrive (again, not all of them). But the Python packets don't, they are all correct! Any idea as to what might be going on?

It is really strange that I can send data properly and I can receive some packets properly. Help is much appreciated. Thanks.

Code added:
Python serial initialization

```
def __init__(self, port, quat_delegate=None, debug_delegate=None, data_delegate=None):

    self.s = serial.Serial(port, 115200)

    self.s.setTimeout(0.1)

    self.s.setWriteTimeout(0.2)
```

The Android part is a bit longer... sorry for that.

```
//constructor
public BluetoothChatService(Context context, Handler handler){
    mAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    mState = STATE_NONE;
    mHandler = handler;
}

/**
 * Start the ConnectThread to initiate a connection to a remote device.
 * @param device  The BluetoothDevice to connect
 * @param secure Socket Security type - Secure (true) , Insecure (false)
 */
public synchronized void connect(BluetoothDevice device, boolean secure){
    if (D) Log.d(TAG, "connect to: " + device);

    // Cancel any thread attempting to make a connection
    if (mState == STATE_CONNECTING){
        if (mConnectThread != null){
            mConnectThread.cancel();
            mConnectThread = null;
        }
    }

    // Cancel any thread currently running a connection
    if (mConnectedThread != null){
        mConnectedThread.cancel();
        mConnectedThread = null;
    }

    // Start the thread to connect with the given device
    mConnectThread = new ConnectThread(device, secure);
    mConnectThread.start();
    setState(STATE_CONNECTING);
}

/**
 * Start the ConnectedThread to begin managing a Bluetooth connection
 * @param socket  The BluetoothSocket on which the connection was made
 * @param device  The BluetoothDevice that has been connected
 */
public synchronized void connected(BluetoothSocket socket, BluetoothDevice
        device, final String socketType){
    if (D) Log.d(TAG, "connected, Socket Type:" + socketType);

    // Cancel the thread that completed the connection
    if (mConnectThread != null){
        mConnectThread.cancel();
        mConnectThread = null;
    }

    // Cancel any thread currently running a connection
    if (mConnectedThread != null){
        mConnectedThread.cancel();
        mConnectedThread = null;
    }

    // Cancel the accept thread because we only want to connect to one device
    if (mSecureAcceptThread != null){
        mSecureAcceptThread.cancel();
        mSecureAcceptThread = null;
    }
    if (mInsecureAcceptThread != null){
        mInsecureAcceptThread.cancel();
        mInsecureAcceptThread = null;
    }

    // Start the thread to manage the connection and perform transmissions
    mConnectedThread = new ConnectedThread(socket, socketType);
    mConnectedThread.start();

    // Send the name of the connected device back to the UI Activity
    Message msg = mHandler.obtainMessage(BluetoothChat.MESSAGE_DEVICE_NAME);
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString(BluetoothChat.DEVICE_NAME, device.getName());
    msg.setData(bundle);
    mHandler.sendMessage(msg);

    setState(STATE_CONNECTED);
}

/**
 * This thread runs while attempting to make an outgoing connection
 * with a device. It runs straight through; the connection either
 * succeeds or fails.
 */
private class ConnectThread extends Thread{
    private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
    private final BluetoothDevice mmDevice;
    private String mSocketType;

    public ConnectThread(BluetoothDevice device, boolean secure){
        mmDevice = device;
        BluetoothSocket tmp = null;
        mSocketType = secure ? "Secure" : "Insecure";

        // Get a BluetoothSocket for a connection with the
        // given BluetoothDevice
        try{
            if(secure){
                tmp = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(
                        MY_UUID_SECURE);
            }else{
                tmp = device.createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(
                        MY_UUID_INSECURE);
            }
        }catch (IOException e){
            Log.e(TAG, "Socket Type: " + mSocketType + "create() failed", e);
        }
        mmSocket = tmp;
    }

    public void run(){
        Log.i(TAG, "BEGIN mConnectThread SocketType:" + mSocketType);
        setName("ConnectThread" + mSocketType);

        // Always cancel discovery because it will slow down a connection
        mAdapter.cancelDiscovery();

        // Make a connection to the BluetoothSocket
        try{
            // This is a blocking call and will only return on a
            // successful connection or an exception
            mmSocket.connect();
        }catch (IOException e){
            // Close the socket
            try{
                mmSocket.close();
            }catch (IOException e2){
                Log.e(TAG, "unable to close() " + mSocketType +
                        " socket during connection failure", e2);
            }
            connectionFailed();
            return;
        }

        // Reset the ConnectThread because we're done
        synchronized(BluetoothChatService.this){
            mConnectThread = null;
        }

        // Start the connected thread
        connected(mmSocket, mmDevice, mSocketType);
    }

    public void cancel(){
        try{
            mmSocket.close();
        }catch (IOException e){
            Log.e(TAG, "close() of connect " + mSocketType + " socket failed", e);
        }
    }
}

/**
 * This thread runs during a connection with a remote device.
 * It handles all incoming and outgoing transmissions.
 */
private class ConnectedThread extends Thread{
    private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
    private final InputStream mmInStream;
    private final OutputStream mmOutStream;

    public ConnectedThread(BluetoothSocket socket, String socketType){
        Log.d(TAG, "create ConnectedThread: " + socketType);
        mmSocket = socket;
        InputStream tmpIn = null;
        OutputStream tmpOut = null;

        // Get the BluetoothSocket input and output streams
        try{
            tmpIn = socket.getInputStream();
            tmpOut = socket.getOutputStream();
        }catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "temp sockets not created", e);
        }

        mmInStream = tmpIn;
        mmOutStream = tmpOut;
    }

    public void run() {
        Log.i(TAG, "BEGIN mConnectedThread");
        byte[] buffer = new byte[23];
        //byte[] buffer = new byte[1024]; //orig*
        int bytes;

        // Keep listening to the InputStream while connected
        while (true){
            try{
                // Read from the InputStream
                bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer);
        //processing of the data goes here, i guess that's not necessary to include
     }
```

The connect method starts a ConnectThread which runs until a connection is successfully established or it fails. Once the connection is established, that thread stops and the ConnectedThread starts. This is just code from the BluetoothChat Android example, with some minor modifications.

Comment: Can you show any of the Python and Java code?  Perhaps a minimal example that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: Sorry, I should have added it before...